# how to read strings which are in multiple lines and to print characters in even digit and characters in odd digit seperated by a space in each stri

Tags: c

This is my C Code

```
int main() {
    int n,i,j,k;
    char ch[10][10000];
    char c;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        while((j<10000)&&(c=getchar()!='\n')){
        ch[i][j]=c;}}
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<strlen(ch[j]);k+=2)
        {
            printf("%c",ch[i][j]);
        }printf("");
        for(k=1;k<strlen(ch[j]);k+=2)
        {
            printf("%c",ch[i][j]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect output  of "pavan" as pvn aa but output is "terminated due to timeout

Answer (score 2):

Lots wrong with your code. First off, you don't initialise `j` with any value. And on each time you read a line of text, you don't reset it to 0. Or in fact ever change the value.

You don't check that `n` is 10 or less. And you also leave a `\n` in the input buffer, so the first line of text you read in, isn't what you're expecting. You'd be better off using `fgets` to read in the entire line and then using `sscanf` to extract out the number.

This loop reads in one too many lines...which might be a way around you not clearing the input before reading in lines, but doesn't fix the problem.

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
```

And then you have this line and it's corresponding one for the odd numbers...

```
for(k=0;k<strlen(ch[j]);k+=2)
```

`j` is still pointing at some undefined value. But you shouldn't be using `j`, you should be using `i`.

```
for(k=0;k<strlen(ch[i]);k+=2)
```

And then inside the loop you don't use `k` at all, so it's pretty pointless. Also using `strlen()` like that means that for time around the loop, it re-calculates the length of the string.

After all the various bugs are fixed your code would look like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int n,i,j;
    char ch[10][10000];

    fgets(ch[0],10000,stdin);
    sscanf(ch[0],"%d",&n);
    if((n>10)||(n<1)) {
        printf("Invalid number\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        fgets(ch[i],10000,stdin);
        if(strchr(ch[i],'\n')) {
            *(strchr(ch[i],'\n'))='\0';
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<strlen(ch[i]);j+=2) {
            printf("%c",ch[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" ");
        for(j=1;j<strlen(ch[i]);j+=2) {
            printf("%c",ch[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is  working but output is pvn and aa are in separate  lines but i want space between them

Comment: That'll be because `fgets` includes the `\n` in the string. I've updated the answer with some code that strips it

Comment: could please tell me the working of fgets() and sscanf() and what is strchr()

Comment: It is working but i dont understand working of sscanf() fgets() and strchr() please explain it to me

Comment: You really should find a source of documentation for the basic C functions. sscanf is just like scanf but it reads from a string. fgets reads in a line of text. strchr locates a character in a string.

Answer (score 1):

in `while((j<10000)&&(c=getchar()!='\n')) ch[i][j]=c;}}` 'j' is not initialized before and not modified in the loop

In case by chance the random value of 'j' is < 10000 you will enter your string but it is saved in a random location corrupting the memory, and probably producing a segmentation fault

Independently of that you do not finish the input strings, when you read '\n' put a '\0' in `ch[i][j]`

Comment: now i intialised and run but output is "terminated due to tineout"

Comment: There are other errors, please look at the other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues:

```
int main() {
    int n,i,j,k;      
    char ch[10][10000];
    char c;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){                            // Use < instead of <=
                                                  // j is not initialized
        while((j<(10000-1))&&(c=getchar()!='\n')){    // missing () around c=getchar()
        ch[i][j]=c;}}                             // j is not incremented 
                                                  // string never terminated
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<strlen(ch[j]);k+=2)             // j should be i
        {
            printf("%c",ch[i][j]);                // j should be k
        }
        printf("");                               // missing space
        for(k=1;k<strlen(ch[j]);k+=2)             // j should be i
        {
            printf("%c",ch[i][j]);                // j should be k
        }printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

fixing that like:

```
#define MAX 10000

int main() {
    int n,i,j=0,k;
    char ch[10][MAX];
    char c;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        j = 0;
        while((j < (MAX-1)) && ((c=getchar()) != '\n')){
            ch[i][j++]=c;
        }
        ch[i][j++]='\0';  // Terminate string 
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<strlen(ch[i]);k+=2)
        {
            printf("%c",ch[i][k]);
        }
        printf(" ");
        for(k=1;k<strlen(ch[i]);k+=2)
        {
            printf("%c",ch[i][k]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

result in:

> Input: 1pavan
>
> Ouput: pvn aa

BTW:

Notice that there is no newline between the number and the string in the input! If you put a newline there, the text string will be empty. This is because `scanf` leaves the newline in the buffer.

Also notice that you don't check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that you got a valid number. So if the input is `abc` (i.e. no number to start with) the variable `n` is uninitialized which may lead to seg fault.

Either check the `scanf`return value and handle errors or at least initialize like: `n = 0;`

Comment: you missed to terminate the input line by the null character. It is the game of the 10000 errors :)

Comment: so`while((j<10000)&&((c=getchar())!='\n')){ch[i][j++]=c;} ch[i][j] = 0; }`

Comment: @bruno Thanks I missed that one

Comment: and of course j must be reset into `for(i=0;i<=n;i++)`, not just set before the for

Comment: @KALYAN I made a minor update to handle the case where the input has no `'\n'` in the first 10000 chars. Does that solve your seg fault?